# Get subString from a string with given indexes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am trying to get a SubString from a string

This is the method I am calling

```
-(NSString *)subStringBetweenStrings:(NSString*)str open:(NSString*)open close:(NSString *)close
{
    if ( str == nil || open == nil || close == nil )
        return nil;

    int start = [str rangeOfString:open].location;
    if (start != -1)
    {
        int end = [str rangeOfString:close].location;
        if ( end != -1)
        {
            return [str substringFromIndex:start]; // DONT WANT
        }
    }
    return nil;       
}
```

I have `start point` and i have `End point`. How can i get subString from start and end index
something like return `[ str subStringWithRange:(start, end)];`

Comment: what is the point of giving a negative point?

Comment: The point is that you even didn't try to read to `NSString` documentation ... But I didn't give you this negative point ...

Comment: right....... so a whole documentation will be always in my mind :) nvrmind

Comment: @umar Documentation is available from the Xcode menu Help->Documentation and API Reference. So while the "whole documentation" may not always be in your mind, it can always be at your fingertips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nitpicking ...

- replace `int start` with `NSUInteger`, that's how `NSRange` `location` is defined,
- don't compare `start` to `-1`, but to `NSNotFound`

... answer ...

`return [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange( start, end - start + 1 )]`